# R - How to create a new vector based on the strings in another vector

Tags: r

I am a beginner coding in R.

I am trying to create a vector based on the strings of another vector. Say:

```
vector_one <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

I want to create a second vector which reads the strings in vector_one, and connects it to new values. So I guess it would be something like:

```
vector_two <- if vector_one == "A" then vector_two == "apple",
              if vector_one == "B" then vector_two == "banana",
              (and so on)
```

so that the end result of my vector_two would be:

```
vector_two <- c("apple", "banana", "cat", "dog")
```

How can I proceed? Thank you for your help in advance.

I'm stuck beyond words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `recode` or even `case_match`:

```
recode(vector_one, 'A' = 'apple', 'B' = 'banana', 'C' = 'cat', 'D' = 'dog')
[1] "apple"  "banana" "cat"    "dog"
```

---

```
case_match(vector_one, 'A'~'apple', 'B' ~ 'banana', 'C'~'cat', 'D'~'dog')
[1] "apple"  "banana" "cat"    "dog"
```

Comment: For the OP, these functions are from `library(dplyr)`. Just a note that `recode` has been superseded in favor of `case_match` in dplyr 1.1.0.

Comment: Thanks so much! I used this method and it worked. And LMc, thank you for the added note!!

Answer (score 3):

In base R you can create a named vector, which is a vector of name-value pairs. The names are the values you want to change and the values are what you want to change to:

```r
nm <- setNames(c("apple", "banana", "cat", "dog"), c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

unname(nm[vector_one]) 
# [1] "apple"  "banana" "cat"    "dog"
```

So when you provide a name, it will return the value that corresponds:

```r
nm["A"]
#       A 
# "apple" 

nm[c("A", "A", "B")]
#        A        A        B 
#  "apple"  "apple" "banana"
```

This returns a named vector, as you can tell, which is why I used the function `unname` to remove the names.

Answer (score 1):

I think some good candidates for this are `dplyr::case_when` or `data.table::fcase`, both with similar methodologies:

```r
vector_one <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
case_when(
  vector_one == "A" ~ "apple",
  vector_one == "B" ~ "banana",
  vector_one == "C" ~ "cat",
  vector_one == "D" ~ "dog"
)
# [1] "apple"  "banana" "cat"    "dog"   
fcase(
  vector_one == "A", "apple",
  vector_one == "B", "banana",
  vector_one == "C", "cat",
  vector_one == "D", "dog"
)
# [1] "apple"  "banana" "cat"    "dog"
```

The biggest difference is that `case_when` uses `cond ~ result` tilde pairs, whereas `fcase` just uses additional arguments (comma-delimited).